# How to show node name in graphs using networkx?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I have the code

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3)])

nx.draw(G)
plt.savefig("graph.png")
plt.show()
```

And it draws the following graph:
[image]

However, I need to display labels.
How do I display the numeric values and words (one, two, three and four) within the nodes of the graph?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You just need to call the **`with_labels=True`** parameter with `nx.Draw()`:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3)])

nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)
plt.savefig("graph.png")
plt.show()
```

You can also call `font_size`, `font_color`, etc.

See the documentation here:
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/drawing.html

Comment: Thank you! I was confused because I was following some [old manuals](http://www.python-course.eu/networkx.php), which this parameter did not appear. To show the number in word, I used `H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four'})` and `nx.draw(H, with_labels=True)`

Comment: Sorry I completely missed the last part regarding relabel